# Docker container from docker cloud on windows

Tags: windows, docker, spring-boot, docker-cloud, kitematic

I've some repositories on docker cloud. I build and deploy it on my home ubuntu server and that work well.

On my home server, I can access these services with their url (like http://registry:8761).

I'm trying to run my service on Kitematic on Windows, all of my services are running on localhost, so my configuration in application.yml where I say that my registry service is on http://registry:8761 doesn't work.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn't know what to do with `http://registry` since it's got no TLD qualifier. I assume your ubuntu server is set up in a way to do all the correct redirections, but with Windows you'd have to add an entry in your `hosts` file that points `http://registry` to `localhost` or wherever it's supposed to go

Comment: It's not via my browser. When I start one of my applications, they are looking for the registry service. I set the `defaultZone: http://registry:8761/eureka/` in the application.yml but on windows they don't find it

Comment: @andy200486 it still applies, could you elaborate on where you're trying to connect to these services from? On the ubuntu server are you also connecting from Ubuntu and on Windows you're connecting from Windows?

Comment: I've modifying my hosts file on windows to point http://registry:8761 to http://localhost:8761, and it works, I can access my eureka service with http://registry:8761 from a browser. But when a service try to register to the service registry, it doesn't work. I got this error : `com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server`